# how does emacs choose which script to initialize with?

Tags: emacs

In both emacs 25.2.2 on Ubuntu 18.10, and 26.2 on arch we are experiencing the following weird behavior:

Ubuntu 18:
there is a .emacs file in my home directory.
If I run emacs, it works

.emacs sets indent style, font, and color

```
(custom-set-faces
  ;; custom-set-faces was added by Custom.
  ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
  ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
  ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 '(default ((t (:inherit nil :stipple nil :background "white" :foreground "black" :inverse-video nil :box nil :strike-through nil :overline nil :underline nil :slant normal :weight bold :height 180 :width normal :foundry "urw" :family "Nimbus Mono L")))))
(set-background-color "black")
(set-foreground-color "green")
```

When emacs is run by gnome-settings, it does not set the font correctly, but does set the indent and the color. I therefore conclude that the font setting is not working when gnome is first set up.

On arch, running emacs looks ok. But then if we load the file and M-x eval-buffer the font changes. Evaluating twice changes the font again. Eval a third time does nothing.

Can anyone explain what is happening, and how we can reliably select a font regardless of when the command is run?

Comment: I find your question(s) confusing. What do you mean when you say emacs is "run by gnome-settings"? Also, what file are you loading in the 'arch' part of your question?

Comment: you can check the value of `user-init-file` to see what init script was used.  You could also set your emacs font in you .Xresources (or equiv. for arch) which would additionally save on emacs startup time